# Consumir servicio WCF con Ajax

Tags: ajax, wcf

Hola comunidad tengo un servicio `WCF` que esta publicado en un servidor X,necesito consumir un método de ese servicio a través de `AJAX`, el método del servicio recibe como parámetro un objeto con dos propiedades, la forma en que estoy consumiendo el servicio es la siguiente:

```
var para = { parameters: { Propiedad1: 'xxx', Propiedad2: 'xxx' } };
        data = JSON.stringify(para);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://RutaServicio/Service.svc/MetodoServicio",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {                
                alert('ok');
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

Pero al consumir el servicio este entra por el error y mensaje es `undefined`, ¿Cómo puedo consumir el servicio de manera correcta?

Comment: Pueden ser muchas las razones. Sin conocer más sobre el servicio es difícil ayudar. Tienes acceso al log del servicio? O mejor aun, puedes depurarlo? Podria ayudarte tambien capturar la trama devuelta con fiddler. Quizás el metodo debería ser Get? O Quizás necesites permisos/ssl... Como ves, sin conocer el servicio es complicado saber lo que sucede

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Answer (score -1):

debes habilitar **GET** en tu Web.Config.
Aqui hay una pregunta parecida y esta detallada le respuesta.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39011474/no-ajax-call-on-wcf-service-with-method

Saludos,
Espero que te ayude.

Comment: En la pregunta yo veo que hace una petición `POST`